# Value of resistor (strange 5 color bands)

Tags: resistors

How to determine value of this resistor by 5 color band which does not make sense according to color code?
It's current sense from small flyback, so I it will be small value.

I see colors:

1. brown (or red)
2. gray (or silver)
3. gold
4. gold
5. black

I tried many online calculators, but none accepts 2 gold bands on position 3 a 4 following by black band.

[image]

Comment: From the linked table, the five bands decode as: `1`, `8`, `x0.1`, `5%`, `Non inductive` = 1.8R 5%, wound such that parasitic inductance is minimised.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Yes, thank you. I did not remember that color bands for wirewound resistors have extra one.